# parse XML file to get <img> tag "src" attributes value

Tags: android, xml, image, src

I am trying to build a app that display the feed of a given twitter account without using Twitter's Oauth, instead I converted the twitter account feed page to an xml format using [Twitrss.me](http://twitrss.me/) the image src is buried inside the img tag under the src attribute

```
<img xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" width="250"
src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/CmEqtEuUoAISIC3.jpg" 
xml:base="http://twitrss.me/twitter_user_to_rss/?user=capcomfighters" />
```

I was able to get all the other tags text content but I have no idea how to access the tag attributes and get the value for specific attribute

also if there is a better way to do this than parsing xml please let me know

I am using this function to get the content of the tags

```
private void ProcessXml(Document data) {
    if (data != null) {
        feedItems=new ArrayList<>();
        Element root = data.getDocumentElement();
        Node channel = root.getChildNodes().item(1);
        NodeList items = channel.getChildNodes();
        for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
            Node currentchild = items.item(i);
            if (currentchild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                FeedItem item=new FeedItem();
                NodeList itemchilds = currentchild.getChildNodes();
                for (int j = 0; j < itemchilds.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node current = itemchilds.item(j);
                    if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
                        item.setTitle(current.getTextContent());
                        item.setDescription(current.getTextContent());
                    }else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")){
                       // item.setDescription(current.getTextContent());
                    }else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")){
                        item.setPubDate(current.getTextContent());
                    }else if (current.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("img")){
                        item.setThumbnailUrl(current.getAttributes().getNamedItem("src").getNodeValue());
                        Log.d("PIC", "ProcessXml: "+current.getAttributes().getNamedItem("src").getNodeValue());
                    }
                }
                feedItems.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ...how are you parsing the XML now?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I added the method

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen can you please help me I'm stuck